# Kafka Stream not displaying output in Control Center

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, stream, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am going through [Confluent Platform Quick Start (Docker)](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html). I am able to create a topic, publish message with `kafka-node`, subscribe with `kafka-console-subscribe.sh` and also `CREATE STREAM` in the KSQL editor. I have also set `auto.offset.reset` to `Earliest` in my query editor.

Firstly, I do **not** see any output the in the window of the control center. Secondly, even though, I am not inserting any more messages into the topic, the count of messages keep increasing by a count that I had originally inserted!

What is missing?

Comment: Partial answer added below to explain why the message counts are going up. 

Would need more information around ' I do not see any output the in the window of the control center.' to say more about the first part:  What version of CP? what command are you running?  Assuming some `select` statement - try running a `PRINT <topic-name> FROM BEGINNING;` on the same statements underlying topic - does that give output?

Answer (score 0):

The message counts will be increasing because the `DataGen` connector the quick start uses continuously produces test data to the Kafka topic.

If you've set `auto.offset.reset` to `Earliest` and not `earliest`, then this may explain why you're not seeing any output